# Splitting a string in python at the colon character

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is my code to split a string list at the colon:

this is more info to maybe help with the question

```
my_file = open("Accounts.txt", "r")
rawAccounts = my_file.read()
Accounts = []
b = 0
j = 0
x = 0
size = 0
dummy= "c"
lessrawAccounts = rawAccounts.split("\n")
while x != 100000:
    size = len(lessrawAccounts[j])
    if lessrawAccounts[j[b]] != ":":
        Accounts[j[b]] = lessrawAccounts[j[b]]
        b = b + 1
    else:
        j = j + 1
        while b <= size:
            Accounts[j[b]] = lessrawAccounts[j[b]]
            b = b + 1
```

Comment: It means your list (matrix) is not as big as the number you put within the []

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store only emails from your list on the basis of semicolons you can use this...

```
lessrawAccounts  = ['JohnDoe@gmail.com:userpass']
Accounts = []
passwords = []
for line in lessrawAccounts:
    Accounts.append(line.split(":")[0])
    passwords.append(line.split(":")[1])
print(Accounts,passwords)
```

Comment: You arent answering the question being asked

Comment: This is good, but i also need to store the password directly after it

Comment: I edited the code for password you can fetch the id and password on the basis of indexes

Answer (score 0):

it would be clearer if you gave examples of the strings you wanted to split.
To answer your "question", the reader needs to parse you code to try to work out what you want to do.

Your question is titled more or less "how to split a string at the : character".

```
before,_,after = "before:after".partition(":")
```

the `partition` function splits a string according to a partition string (it can be more than one character). It returns three values, I have discarded the middle value, since the middle value is the partitioning string.

Comment: sorry, in my original post it had such things, I was told it was taken away by an edit that was not made by me. Thanks for the solution though

Comment: Ok, that's confusing :) Stick with it, Stack Overflow can seem a bit bureaucratic at the start, but it's worth perservering. Just remember to make your questions as easy to understand as you for someone reading them quickly. Precise questions, specific examples, and your own attempts, but limit this to exactly what you are asking about.